# onTapGesture modifier works from the second time in swiftui

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I wrote a tool for opening quickly Xcode projects

Mine onTapGesture modifier doesn’t work when I click the first time. It works as expected form the second time and so on. Can it be that my app window is not active?

Source code:
https://github.com/DKalachniuk/XcodeProjects
File ProjectIcon.swift

```
struct ProjectIcon: View {
    let project: Project
    @EnvironmentObject var preferences: Preferences

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(Color.clear)
                .background(Color(self.project.color.color))
                .cornerRadius(8)

            Text(String(self.project.name.first ?? "-").capitalized)
                .font(.system(size: 14, weight: Font.Weight.semibold))
                .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 4, bottom: 0, trailing: 4))
                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
        }
        .frame(width: 24, height: 24)
        .onTapGesture {
            let newColor = CodableColorPicker.shared.pickRandomColor()
            self.preferences.changeProjectsColor(self.project, newColor: newColor)
        }
    }
}
```

Update: Interesting  observation about this bug. if i click somewhere on the window and then click project icon then it works immediately

Comment: Please paste your code directly in the question, don't post links to GitHub.

Comment: You might want to take a look at the [contentShape](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/contentshape(_:eofill:)) modifier.

Comment: Same here. Only first activating the window with the first click and then clicking again makes the onTapGesture work. Did you ever find a fix for this? This is only with .onTapGesture. Buttons work directly without first activating the window.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following (tested with Xcode 12 / macOS 10.15.5)

```
.frame(width: 24, height: 24)
.contentShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8))     // << here !!
.onTapGesture {
```

*Note: btw, review logic of `pickRandomColor()` it does not take into account color stored in Preferences, just in case.*

Comment: Asperi thanks for the note. i will review the logic. Interesting  observation about this bug. if i click somewhere on the window and then click project icon then it works immediately